# Multiple DataList Binding in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I Have a two Datalist that Binding together , The First one print the ID,SYSDATE and BUTTON , The second one print the details about the first one ,,, 
I wanna know how to show the second DataList when i click the "Button" on the First DataList
Any Help Please
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataList2 = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("DataList2");
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("id");
    DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("some query", m_SqlConnection);
    da2.Fill(dataSet2, "sub");
    DataList2.DataSource = dataSet2.Tables["sub"];
    DataList2.DataBind();

}
void button1_click(){show the second datalist}
```

Comment: You just have to pass `hf.Value` which is `id` to second query.

Comment: @user2992033 Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

On your first `DataList` create the event `ItemCommand` and you can capture the button click event (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df6hth3s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)):

```
protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "ButtonName")
   {      
      // Bind second DataList 
   }
}
```